# link without www not working properly when i have <base href> with www in it

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If i put `<base href="http://www.example.com"/>` then if I go in my browser to WWW.example.com everything is fine, but when I go to example.com some things with Cascade style sheet files and java script files are screwed (for example icons in bootstrap don't show) until i click some other page on my site so it transforms to WWW.example.com/page and from there everything is fine... I have tried with `<base href="http://example.com"/>` and going to WWW.example.com and it is same just other way around. How can i fix this?

Comment: Just a word of warning here regarding relying on the base href:  there are lots of badly written crawlers out there that neglect to look for this.  As a result, they will generate hundreds of 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `base` tag to the respective sub-domain that the user has entered. Or you can just redirect all your requests to the `www` sub-domain with a simple `mod_rewrite` rule.

Going the first way, I believe you can do that with javascript, not 100% sure though. Try having this at the start of your code, having the base tag with `www` as default.

```
if(document.URL.indexOf('://www.')===-1){
    var base = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
    base.href = base.href.replace('://www.','://');
}
```

The other way is to use `mod_rewrite`, which is easily done with `.htaccess` files in apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I personally think the second way would be the better choice. Firstly because I'm not completely sure that the javascript scenario will work at all, and even if it does, javascript is not ran on all browsers and especially on bots. So I'd advice you to use `.htaccess`. Good luck!

Comment: is any of those 2 better than the other? and how could i get the sub-domain that the user has entered?

Answer (score 0):

How about edit your DNS information to set that "example.com" link to the real ip and didn`t as a 301 redirect